# group rows (dates) and summarize serveral columns (several measured values for eacht date) in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I use Python Pandas and load a table like this from Postgres:

```
date                  v00  v01  v02  v03
2001-01-01 00:00:00   30   40   50   100
2001-01-01 00:00:00   80   120  20    60
2001-02-01 00:00:00   20    70  50    20
```

I want to group the Date rows using Pandas and summarize the values. The result should look like this

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00   500
2001-02-01 00:00:00   160
```

I can group the dates and summarize the values separately, but not in one view.

My results are

```
1 220
2 280
3 160
```

And

```
date                  v00  v01  v02  v03
2001-01-01 00:00:00   110  160  70   160
2001-02-01 00:00:00   20    70  50    20
```

Thats the Code:

```py
import psycopg2 as ps 
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl


conn = ps.connect(host="host", user="user", password="password", dbname="Python_ueben")

cur = conn.cursor()

print('connect')

""" schema = input("Geben Sie das Schema ein")
table = input(" Geben Sie die Tabele ein") """


def load_data(schema, table):

    sql_command = "SELECT * FROM {}.{};".format(str(schema), str(table))
    print (sql_command)

    # Load the data
    data = pd.read_sql(sql_command, conn)

    groub = data.groupby(['date']) # group Date and save in variable
    print(data.sum(axis=1, skipna=True)) #sum values v00 - v03
    print(groub.sum(axis=1, skipna=True)) # group and sum, but not the right result
    #print(data.groupby(['date']).sum(axis=0, skipna=False))



load_data('public', 'zeitreihe')
```

Comment: is `date` a column or your index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Date` is column first aggregate sum and then `sum` per `axis=1`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Date').sum().sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='sum')
print (df1)
                  Date  sum
0  2001-01-01 00:00:00  500
1  2001-02-01 00:00:00  160
```

Or create `index` by `Date` column, then sum all rows and last sum per index (aggregate sum per index):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date').sum(axis=1).sum(level=0).reset_index(name='sum')
```

If `Date` is index solution above is simplify:

```
df1 = df.sum(axis=1).sum(level=0).reset_index(name='sum')

df1 = df.sum(level=0).sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='sum')
```

Comment: Thanks! Even the first solution worked. Great and really fast :D